# Drag and drop in read only rich text box

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I am trying implement drag and drop feature in RichTextBox (windows common control). It works fine using the code shown below. However, the drag drop event is not getting triggered when I set the ReadOnly property to true. Is there anything that I am missing? or is that the right behaviour ? Please advice.

```
private void rtb_dragdrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Test");       
}

private void rtb_dragenter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, setting the ReadOnly property to true in a RichTextBox will turn off the ability to do Drag and Drop operations.

A simple hack to *mimic* a read only RichTextBox:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

  public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    rtb.EnableAutoDragDrop = true;
    rtb.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(rtb_KeyDown);
  }

  void rtb_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
  }
}
```

Now your Drag and Drop operation should work automatically with the `EnabledAutoDragDrop` property set to true.  No need to handle those drag enter and drop events.

Comment: I think Microsoft assumed content d&d. If so, disabling d&d on a readonly RTB makes sense. But in my case, it is a simple readonly file viewer which has a readonly RTB on it, so I think file d&d on it should be allowed anywhere including on the RTB. 

In case of TextBox, d&d seems to be simply delegated to the form. Is there any way to do that with RTB? Basically, I just want to d&d on the form itself, and the readonly RTB gets in my way.