# Can anyone tell me why the AllowDrop does not work with text boxes

Tags: c#, wpf

I currently have a program which has a menu band at the top and a text box below it where a text is displayed. At the bottom is a normal text box which serves as search bar. My current problem is that I activated AllowDrop for the whole window (even for the textboxes themselves)but it doesn't work everywhere only for the textboxes.It should be possible to drop the file anywhere and insert the contained text into the textbox.Who has an idea why it doesn't work for the textboxes ?

```
<Window x:Class="SuchToolBuild.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SuchToolBuild"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        AllowDrop="True"
        KeyDown="Forward"
        KeyUp="Backwards"
        Title="SuchTool" Height="800" Width="1280">
```

Comment: Your xaml code does not include the textbox you are refering to.

Comment: I was suggesting an edit to add more xaml because the textbox could be placed in a cointainer with `AllowDrop="false"` sometimes making a MCVE points out the cause of the problem

Comment: What does `IsReadOnly` do? Does it work if you set it to `False`? Also, please provide the [mcve] **in the question itself** so we can repro the issue. _Also, this is 100% why `I don't need to show the textbox` is often a bad response - by hiding part of your code you made it harder for us to show you your mistake._

Comment: Perhaps ReadOnly enforces it cannot be altered (disabling the AllowDrop). Not WPF, [but same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491988/drag-and-drop-in-read-only-rich-text-box)

Comment: Does the behaviour occur if you run the application from Windows Explorer (double click the EXE) rather than through Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

First i made 2 new Event Handler in the constructor

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;

        RichTextBoxForOpenText.AddHandler(RichTextBox.DragOverEvent, new DragEventHandler(RichTextBox_DragOver), true);

        RichTextBoxForOpenText.AddHandler(RichTextBox.DropEvent, new DragEventHandler(RichTextBox_Drop), true);
    }
```

Then I decided exactly what should happen at these events.

```
 private void RichTextBox_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.All;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
        }
        e.Handled = false;
    }

    private void RichTextBox_Drop(object sender,DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(System.Windows.DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            GetTextFromDroppetFile(e);


        }
    }
```

And this is my method to extract the text from one of the dropped files.

```
 private void GetTextFromDroppetFile(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        //Die RichTextBox wird hier erstmal gecleart
        RichTextBoxForOpenText.Document.Blocks.Clear();

        string[] filenames = e.Data.GetData(System.Windows.DataFormats.FileDrop) as string[];
        foreach (var name in filenames)
        {

            RichTextBoxForOpenText.AppendText(File.ReadAllText(name));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this the answer to your own question? If yes, please mark it as the solution with the green check on the left side of the answer. If this is an extent to your question, then please edit your question and delete this answer.